# string.Formatter does not accept "{}" template?

Tags: python, formatting, formatter

Python's [Formatter class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) "allows you to create and customize your own string formatting behaviors using the same implementation as the built-in format() method". Since one can do

```
>>> '{}'.format(3.14)
'3.14'
```

and

```
>>> format(3.14, '')
'3.14'
```

I was expecting the following to work too:

```
>>> string.Formatter().format('{}', 3.14)
(…)
KeyError: ''
```

Is there any standard way of handling this very usual and simple formatting string with a Formatter? or must the Formatter be customized before behaving more like Python's `format()`? is this really doable in a [robust way](http://bugs.python.org/issue5237#msg83559) (thread-safe,…)?

Comment: My guess would be that formatters are not required to understand `{}` because that was not valid in Python 2.6 and 3.0 (`{0}` was required instead).

Comment: The question *Should string.Format also support auto-numbering?* is discussed in http://bugs.python.org/issue5237#msg83559

Comment: The thread you cite is interesting. It looks like not much has changed on this front since it was started in 2009… If this is confirmed, I would accept this as the response to the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original implementation of new-style string formatting in Python 2.6/3.0 did not allow empty `{}` templates. The change that allows them is documented as [issue 5237: Allow auto-numbered replacement fields in str.format() strings](http://bugs.python.org/issue5237). On that page, [message 83559 from Eric V. Smith](http://bugs.python.org/issue5237#msg83559) ponders the question whether `string.Format` also should support auto-numbering (I suppose he means `string.Formatter`) and concludes against it.

A patch has been proposed in [issue 13598: string.Formatter doesn't support empty curly braces "{}"](http://bugs.python.org/issue13598).

Comment: The discussion dates back to 2009: you are implying that the conclusions from that time are the latest available ones and are still in effect, right?